# Writing to Excel in jxl

Tags: java, excel

These are the imports

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
```

The code is throwing error at the first line import java.io
But after importing I get another error "use try catch"

```
WritableWorkbook workbook =Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\IronMan.xls"));
    WritableSheet sheet=workbook.createSheet("Tony", 0);
    Label label=new Label(0,0,"Real Name");
    sheet.addCell(label);
    Label label1=new Label(1,0,"Character Name");
    sheet.addCell(label1);
    Label label2=new Label(2,0,"Ability");
    sheet.addCell(label2);
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see an issue here, the exception is expected as we are dealing with File IO which can fail at times. You may adapt the below code and it should work for you.

```
import java.io.File;

import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WritableWorkbook workbook;
        try {
            workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\IronMan.xls"));
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Tony", 0);
            Label label = new Label(0, 0, "Real Name");
            sheet.addCell(label);
            Label label1 = new Label(1, 0, "Character Name");
            sheet.addCell(label1);
            Label label2 = new Label(2, 0, "Ability");
            sheet.addCell(label2);
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works as expected.